# sql result for TOAD query

Tags: sql, database, toad

I'm looking for a way to break data within a cell and create new lines recycling another cells value, need some assistance.

| ROLE | ROLE RIGHTS |
| --- | --- |
| AB-ATL | =READ;=TOTAL;=HAPPY;=MAD |

Would like to be able to write to where I can get the following result

| ROLE | ROLE RIGHTS |
| --- | --- |
| AB-ATL | READ |
| AB-ATL | TOTAL |
| AB-ATL | HAPPY |
| AB-ATL | MAD |

Thus breaking up the cells value into 4 lines with the constant being the role.  Is this accomplished through SUBSTRINGs??

Comment: You can write a **recursive query** to iterate through the substrings (or in Oracle write a PL/SQL pipelined function to split the string).

Comment: The problem here is actually the database. If you are interested in the separate role rights, store them separately or you are violating the first normal form.

Comment: Normalize your database model at least to 1NF: "One value per column". This "Database 101" knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

since you tagged toad I am going to assume oracle. If that assumption is correct.
you can use the regexp_substr along with connect by level.  to split a string into rows as described here.  https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/split-comma-separated-values-into-rows-in-oracle-database

here is the fiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6a151b5a87ed2bd81ddf938209ba42df

```
with rws as (
  select '=READ;=TOTAL;=HAPPY;=MAD' str from dual
)
  select regexp_substr (
           str,
           '[^=;]+',
           1,
           level
         ) value
  from   rws
  connect by level <= 
    length ( str ) - length ( replace ( str, '=' ) ) + 1;
```

Comment: Was able to use what you provided, much appreciated!!